# Does Egon actually collect Spores, Molds, and Fungus?

Tags: ghostbusters

When Janine is trying to chat up Egon in *Ghostbusters*, he responds with:

> I collect spores, moulds and fungus.

However, there's no mycological samples or equipment visible in the Fire Station.

We've seen Egon be canny with people, e.g. signaling to Peter just how much they can <strike>fleece</strike> charge the hotelier for capturing Slimer and carrying out social experiments at the start of Ghostbusters 2.

Is there any evidence that Egon *does* collect these or, given that he is quite canny, is this a case of him trying to put off Janine to keep the work environment working smoothly. Or this just a characterisation that he's just a dork that can't talk to women?

Comment: The Wikipedia page for Egon states that as one of his hobbies, but doesn't give a citation for that. It would be reasonable then that he leaves the hobby work at home, given that he is a parapsychologist by profession and business work is done at the firehouse.

Answer (score 1):

We see his collection in the movie sequel [*Ghostbusters: Afterlife*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4513678/).

[image]

And in the accompanying video game, [*Ghostbusters: Spirits Unleashed*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt21033386/)

[image]